# Failed to Clone Object {0}. Error in IBM FileNET 5.2 How to Solve this?

Tags: c#, dms, ecm, filenet

The Following Code display Failed to Clone Object {0} error. While uploading a document from a local system via C#.NET Code.

Actually I tested this in 7 systems 5 systems showing error. But on other two code works Correctly.

Mostly tested in Win 7, Server 2008R2.

By putting try Catch i identified, the error takes place in this following Line

doc.Save(RefreshMode.Refresh);

i have posted the Exception code below.

If you have idea about it.. post back.

```
 private void uploadDocument(string file)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("upload Doc" + file);

        System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.WaitCursor;

        IDocument doc = null;

        IObjectStore os = ce.FetchOS(config.objectstore().Trim());

        //MessageBox.Show("os" + os);



        doc = CEUtil.CreateDocument(true, file, os, "Document");

        MessageBox.Show("After CreteDoc1");

        doc = CEUtil.CreateDocument(os, "Document");

        MessageBox.Show("After CreteDoc2");

        doc.Properties["DocumentTitle"] = Path.GetFileName(file);
        //doc.MimeType = "text/plain";

        MessageBox.Show("After Create Doc Method");
        try
        {

            doc.ContentElements = CEUtil.CreateContentElementList(file);

            MessageBox.Show("Before doc.Save");

            doc.Save(RefreshMode.REFRESH);
        }
        catch (Exception cee)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(cee.ToString());
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Save in Doc");
        try
        {

            IReferentialContainmentRelationship rcr = CEUtil.FileContainable(os, doc, fileInFolder);

            MessageBox.Show("Before 2nd Save");

            rcr.Save(RefreshMode.NO_REFRESH);
        }
        catch (Exception EC)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(EC.ToString());
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Second Save Complted");
        try
        {

            CEUtil.checkInDoc(doc);
        }
        catch (Exception EE)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Mess : ChecK In : " + EE.ToString());
        }
        MessageBox.Show("After Check in");

        System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default;

        MessageBox.Show("Document created");
    }
```

### Exception 1:

---

```
ExceptionCode=E_OBJECT_CLONE_FAILED  Id=FNRCE0047  Class=FileNet.Api.Exception.ErrorRecord Source=FileNet.Api.Exception.EngineRuntimeException Description=Failed to clone object {0}. stackTrace=   at FileNet.Apiimpl.Util.ObjectCloner.DeepCopy(Object oldObj) at FileNet.Apiimpl.Core.EngineObjectImpl.GetModifiedData()
```

### Exception 2:

---

```
ExceptionCode=API_PROPERTY_NOT_IN_CACHE  Id=FNRCA0024  Class=FileNet.Api.Exception.ErrorRecord Source=FileNet.Api.Exception.EngineRuntimeException Description=The Name property was not found in the properties collection. stackTrace=   at FileNet.Apiimpl.Property.PropertiesImpl.get_Item(String propertyName)
```

Answer (score 0):

We have the same issue, putting FileNETApi.dll in the GAC solved it.